# How to access this.state from nested objects in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-native, bind

I have a simple component like so:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Statistics extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  render() {
    var config = {
      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function() {
            console.log(this.state.data);
          }
        }
      }
    };

    return (null);
  }
}
```

How can I access the data array within the state inside load function?

## Note

I don't want to bind the `load().bind(this)` function.

Thanks for the consideration.

## Edit

This question is different, in that we're dealing with a scope that we're forced not to use this keyword at all. Please check my updated question above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach: In the first line of your render function, you can save a reference to the `state`.

`const state = this.state;`

Then just reference component state using the constant `state`.

Comment: but then the state will always be the same.

Comment: just use `const thisPtr = this` and reference `thisPtr.state` later on

Comment: @OOP no it wont. The state will be updated everytime the component re-renders.